# Implementation of Dropbox API ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, dropbox

I am trying to consume the Dropbox API in the ASP.NET Core framework, but I am getting the following error:

> 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located
>   assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'.

I have installed the Dropbox API using the NuGet command `Install-Package Dropbox.Api`.

I am attaching a screenshot of the error below.

[image: Error screenshot]]

Comment: Can you please post your App.config and packages.config?

Comment: @Colwin: User used wrong tags. Question is about ASP.NET Core, which doesn't have packages.config, since the packages are managed inside the csproj files

Comment: Hmm okay. Yeah if it's core there won't be a packages.config

Comment: Also, it looks like it's failing on loading `System.Net.Http` itself, not the Dropbox library. There are some questions with this error already: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Could+not+load+file+or+assembly+%27System.Net.Http%2C+Version%3D4.1.1.0%22

Comment: please find attached link for csproj file information which contain package information 

http://prntscr.com/fkenwg

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy/paste the code into the question itself.